# EC2 django nginx, double firewall 8000 + 80

Tags: ubuntu, server, devops, production, hostname

If I have a django app on port 8000 internally connecting to nginx and nginx listening 80 publically, do i need to open 8000 on security groups **AND** ufw? or just on ufw?

*Since 8000 will basically be used only for internal connection I guess*

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to open 8000 if you are using nginx to serve Django.